Using Lua FFI in dnsdist
How can i use Lua FFI for LuaFFIAction() in my dnsdist's configuration file?
In doc: Invoke a Lua FFI function that accepts a pointer to a dnsdist_ffi_dnsquestion_t object, whose bindings are defined in dnsdist-lua-ffi.hh.
Do I need include dnsdist-lua-ffi.hh in my C/C++ code and all dependencies for use dnsdist_ffi_dnsquestion_t?
If I only include dnsdist-lua-ffi.hh, it need all headers into it, and this include a lot of files.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
